# Razor get current controller's User friendly name from route

Tags: razor, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have friendly urls like this /en/friendly-url and that maps to /en/home.
I would like to be able to get the "friendly-url" controller name.
Currently i'm trying to use

```
@{
    string currentController = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
    string currentAction = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString();
}
```

But that returns **home** instead of **friendly-url**

Is there a way to get that section of the url?

Comment: `context.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();` will return the URL in the address bar -- if that helps.  You will need to use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;` as well.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the route segment that corresponds to "controller" when you say "friendly url". If so, then there's no way to retrieve that specifically. It's only for routing and while it gets mapped to a controller in due course, there is no true 1-to-1 correlation between the two.

Comment: For example, the "controller" part of the roue could be literally anything: from just the name of your controller even multiple paths such as "foo/bar/baz". Additionally, *multiple* routes could be defined, so the same controller could be accessed be "foo", "bar" or "foo/bar", etc. In other words, routing is not two-way. You can get to a controller from a particular route, but you cannot necessary get to a particular route from a controller.